# Web application is going down, After I start taking MYSQL dump

Tags: mysql, jive

Tried to push the process to background on linux and also tried with **-q** command:
mysqldump -q -u root -p root database_name > dumpName.sql doesn't seems to be useful.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely to the fact, that mysqldump locks the table during backup.

When you're using InnoDB tables, you can use the `--single-transaction` parameter. Make sure to read the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html):

> - --single-transaction
>
> This option sets the transaction isolation mode to REPEATABLE READ and
>   sends a START TRANSACTION SQL statement to the server before dumping
>   data. It is useful only with transactional tables such as InnoDB,
>   because then it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time
>   when START TRANSACTION was issued without blocking any applications.
>
> When using this option, you should keep in mind that only InnoDB
>   tables are dumped in a consistent state. For example, any MyISAM or
>   MEMORY tables dumped while using this option may still change state.
>
> While a --single-transaction dump is in process, to ensure a valid
>   dump file (correct table contents and binary log coordinates), no
>   other connection should use the following statements: ALTER TABLE,
>   CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE. A consistent
>   read is not isolated from those statements, so use of them on a table
>   to be dumped can cause the SELECT that is performed by mysqldump to
>   retrieve the table contents to obtain incorrect contents or fail.
>
> The --single-transaction option and the --lock-tables option are
>   mutually exclusive because LOCK TABLES causes any pending transactions
>   to be committed implicitly.

When you're using MyISAM tables (not recommended), you're pretty much doomed. Then the best option is, to set up replication to another host. To take backups, stop replication on the slave, start the slave again when mysqldump finished. (google this, I won't explain it here in detail).

Another possible solution would be to use xtrabackup from Percona. Again, google and read the **whole** manual! I can't stress this enough.

Comment: awesome tweak dude, you saved my day